# Project References within a Visual Studio Solution in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, architecture

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to refactor some code by means of an "Anti Corruption Layer".

This is the as-is state of projects:

```
[WebSolution.Api]
[WebSolutions.Services]
```

[WebSolution.Api]⇢ [WebSolutions.Services] ⇢ ***superPackage***

The issue at hand is [WebSolutions.Services] is currently using a NuGet package (let's call it ***superPackage***) which we are trying to get rid of.

Unfortunately, that NuGet package is too deeply integrated within the [WebSolutions.Services] project.

As an interim step, what we are trying to do is to extract the dependency by means of an Anti-Corruption Layer.

This is the new state of projects:

```
[WebSolution.Api]
[WebSolutions.Services]
[WebSolutions.Dependency]
```

[WebSolution.Api]⇢ [WebSolutions.Services] ⇢ [WebSolutions.Dependency] ⇢ ***superPackage***

My attempts as follows:

- Create an adapter that interfaces ***superPackage*** in [WebSolutions.Dependency]
- Remove the call from [WebSolutions.Services] to ***superPackage***, instead calling [WebSolutions.Dependency], which will then call ***superPackage***

The challenge I was facing was that when I removed the ***superPackage***  NuGet package from [WebSolutions.Services], and added a project reference to [WebSolutions.Dependency], the compiler was throwing errors, insisting that ***superPackage*** needs to be referenced by [WebSolutions.Services].

I was under the assumption that since [WebSolutions.Dependency] had a NuGet dependency on ***superPackage***, referencing [WebSolutions.Dependency] from [WebSolutions.Services] will give me those dependencies for free.

Appreciate any advice, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't use any of the classes of the "superPackage" in the interface functions you are calling from Api and Services.